# Is it possible to insert a form within an html table?

Tags: html, forms

Multiple forms in one table, these forms last for varying lengths of rows, however this does not seem to work:

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

I believe a table has a definite structure, and this cannot be interlaced with other structures, but is there a tidy work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think there is. Separate tables are out of the question?

Comment: Tables are for presenting tabular data. You should probably use CSS for laying out forms. Can you give more context for why you might want to use forms embedded in tables?

Comment: Ziggy: forms have a certain tendency to *be* tabular...

Answer (score 5):

No. According to this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1
table may contain only these:

```
TABLE --
     (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
```

But you can use something like this

```
<div class=table>
  <form>
    <div class=cell>...</div>   
    <div class=cell>...</div>   
  </form>
</div>
```

with styles:

```
div.table { display:table; }
div.table > form { display:table-row; }
div.table > form > div.cell { display:table-cell; }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. I guess you want it that way to have both forms aligned in a table, right?

If you are allowed javascript on the page, you could add the different text boxes etc. inside the `<td>` elements, and attach `onchange` event handlers to these boxes to populate the corresponding (hidden) fields in your actual forms.

Comment: After a bit of considering I have opted for a javascript route.. I have planted hidden forms at the end of the table. These forms contain the fields required and a bit of java updates their values to the actual fields in the table.

Thanks everyone for help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

It would be a problem in all HTML ... including both XHTML and HTML5.

[XHTML table dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) ..

`<!ELEMENT table (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>`

Answer (score 0):

Not between `<tr>` tags.  They should work outside of `<table>` or inside of `<td>` though.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to have two forms in a single table if you're looking to put them on multiple rows. The bigger the table, the longer it takes for the browser to load and display it. Instead, give each form its own table and place the table tags within the form tags, like so:

```
<form method="GET" action="foo.sh">
  <table>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Except then the columns in each table won't necessarily be aligned with each other. Which defeats the purpose of using a table at all (for aligning tabular data).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! No problem to HTML5.
Now table tags are just a shorthand for table styling rules.

Comment: Where did you read that about HTML5?
I think this 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element is pretty clear on what is allowed inside table.

Comment: @c-smile Please read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#collections-0

Comment: Are you saying tables implement collections? The HTMLTableElement in c-smile's link clearly isn't implementing collections.